# Input field placeholder not visible on Ios safari

Tags: html, css

Here is my code for input field and placeholder. Don't know why its not working on ios safari but the same is working on other devices.

```
            .form input {
        margin-top: 30px;
        border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: transparent;
        outline: none;
        width: 50%;
        /* padding: 18px 15px;
        font-size: 14px; */
        line-height: 40px;
        height: 50px;
        padding: 0 15px;
        font-family: "Campan";
        color: #3d8559;
        position: relative;
        }
        .form input::placeholder {
        font-size: 14px;
        transition: 400ms;
        position: absolute;
        top: 32%;
        left: 10px;
        color: #8e8e8e;
        }
```

I have also tried the code below but not working

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        color: #000;
        opacity: 1;
        }
        ::-moz-placeholder {
        /* Firefox 19+ */
        color: #777;
        }
        :-ms-input-placeholder {
        color: #777;
        }
        :-moz-placeholder {
        /* Firefox 18- */
        color: #777;
        }
```

Comment: Which version of iOS? [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/css-placeholder) says it's supported in iOS 10.3 and later, and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder) agrees.

Comment: @RichardDeeming since 10.3 is unpreffixed version, in older version there are prefixed `:placeholder`.